# Extract only whole word using grep

Tags: regex, grep, match, exact-match

I've got a big text file. I need to extract all the lines which contains the exact word "DUSP1". 
Here an example of the lines:

```
9606    ENSP00000239223 DUSP1   BLAST
9606    ENSP00000239223 DUSP1-001 Ensembl
```

I want to retrieve the first line but not the second one.

I tried several commands as:

```
grep -E "^DUSP1"
grep '\<DUSP1\>'
grep '^DUSP1$'
grep -w DUSP1
```

But none of them seem to work. Which option should I use?

Comment: How exactly is the "exact word" defined? And your 3rd example would only find lines with only the word "DUSP1" ... So you want lines with "^DUSP1[[:space:]]+" ?

Comment: Could you provide sample file content. The 2nd, 3rd, 4th commands works for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that a *dash* (-) is considered by `grep` as a word delimiter.

You should try this command  :

```
grep '\sDUSP1\s' file
```

to ensure that there's spaces around your word.
Or use *words boundaries* :

```
grep '\bDUSP1\b' file
```

Answer (score 32):

If you want to grep exactly the whole word, you can use word boundaries like this:

```
grep '\bDUSP1\b'
```

This matches for the exact word at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, there are not always spaces before and after (what about when it's the last word?).

Comment: this is great. It also matches `setting=DUSP1` and `my/folder/to/DUSP1`, but not `DUSP123`

Comment: I had to use double quotes for the Windows version of GNU grep. Single quotes did not work.

Comment: Yep, this should be the answer with the big green checkmark. :D

Comment: this still greps DUSP1-001 for me

Comment: no does not work - still greps words with DUSP1-xxx

Answer (score 2):

adding to what sputpick said, it could either be that or:

```
grep '\sDUSP1$' file
```

if the DUSP1 is the end of the line.