# How to exclude hyphen as word separator in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep, solaris

I am unable to `grep` for exact word match containing hyphen as in

```
/home/imper-home,3,0,0,0,jim.imper,NONE,NONE,NONE,http://sanjose                                                                                                                                 
/home/imper,15,10,3,30,jim.imper,NONE,NONE,NONE,http://sanjose-age
```

I tried

```
grep -w imper
```

> but it returns both /home/imper-home and /home/imper.

I want only /home/imper-home to returned by using,

```
grep -wv /home/imper
```

Comment: `grep 'imper-' file` ?

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616012/grep-extract-only-whole-word

Comment: I need it in general for any variable not only for "imper".Excluding hyphen in word match in grep

Comment: @blackSmith that did not work.  I had checked it before posting this question.

Comment: If you have access to the `p` flag, why don't you simply use `grep -P  '(/home/imper)(?=,)' filename --color`. Regarding the answer I mentioned, I just wanted to make you aware of the issue with `-`.

Comment: its a solaris server, unfortunately -P option doesnt work in there for grep

Comment: If @123's answer doesn't work for you, the question is not clear enough. Moreover, it seems like you're trying to solve x, but asking for y which is the wrong approach to start with.

Comment: as I said I need to grep any particular string as in "black" and "black-home" or "black-art" , if I use grep -w "black" all those return.I do not want that.

Comment: The question is still unclear to me, and Rany's concern about this being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) seems valid. Please edit your question, and include your underlying problem, the *reason* you think you want to do this. It may very well be that there's another way to solve your problem that is easier or better.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in general:

```
word=imper
grep -w "$word" file | grep -v "$word-"
```